# How to measure the one-way speed of light

Tags: speed-of-light

I've a idea for measuring. Pretend you have two clocks with connected light detectors, directly next to each other, and let them connect so the time on both is identical. Then you set one up at the beginning of a distance of exact, what should I say, 1 kilometer, the other on the end of that. You let light pass through so the first clock stops the timer and a few moments later the second. The difference is the time. Please let me know if this works.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? That is how you measure every velocity, in essence.

Comment: Your are trying to measure the [one way speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_speed_of_light).  No one has succeeded in doing this.

Comment: I don't see what's non-mainstream about this question.

Comment: For the record, I voted to close as unclear rather than non-mainstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could try measuring the speed of light that way. Since the speed is about 300,000 km per second, the one way trip would take about 3 microseconds, so your clocks would have to be capable of recording very small time intervals very accurately, and your detectors would have to have reaction time very much less than a microsecond, and you would have to synchronise the two clocks very  precisely, and so on. You would also have to measure your kilometre quite carefully if you wanted to reduce errors associated with uncertainties in the distance.

However, even if you did all that, you could not prove that your clocks remained in synch when you moved one of them to a point a kilometre away, so people could still argue about the validity of the result you achieved.

Answer (score 3):

Any measurement of a one way speed necessarily includes two distinct clocks in different places, and hence requires a definition for when the clocks are in sync. The method you propose is sometimes called "slow clock transport" and is one of several equivalent methods of synchronizing clocks that result in the one way speed of light being measured to be the same as the two way speed of light.

The "problem" (such as it is) is that one *can* define other methods of synchronizing clocks which cause the one way speed of light to be different in different directions. This is basically an arbitrary and somewhat silly thing to do, and makes expressing the laws of physics much harder, but it causes no logical contradiction. Since the way we synchronize clocks is basically arbitrary, physicists choose the simple method you suggested and just *define* the one way speed of light to be the same as the round-trip speed.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to measure the 1km very accurately...

Anyway the measurement is now redundant, since 1983 the [speed of light](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed_of_light) has become exactly 299,292,458 m/s, due to the new definition of the meter.

Comment: I mean measuring the one-way speed of light. The speed you give me know is measured with a mirror, I asume.

Comment: @ Seppe Huinink  the meter has been defined as the distance light travels in 1/299792458 of a second

Comment: The problem is, once you have moved the clocks apart, how do you guarantee that they are still synchronised? Any means of communication between them to confirm synchronicity relies on the assumption that the signal speed is independent of direction. So if your concern is that measuring *c* via a 2-way path is somehow invalid, you will have the same 'problem' in your suggested measurement method.